# Is it possible to have Python read one function before another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I was just wondering if a feature like this existed in Python.

My Code:

```
import time
def loop():
    global x
    x=int(input("Time for:"))
    timer()

def timer():
    global x
    for n in range(0,(x)):
        time.sleep(1)
        print (x)
        x=x-1
    print("Times Up"+"\n")
    loop()

print("Clock's Ticking")
loop()
```

Could I possibly make Python read `timer()` before `loop()`

Comment: *"I want Python to read `def timer():` before `def loop():`."* Why?

Comment: Because if it doesnt then a error would show up.

Comment: That's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want to fix an error, ask "How do I fix this error?". Don't ask about a weird thing that you think will be the solution. What's the error anyway?

Comment: What makes you think this is possible in C++, anyway?

Comment: timer() not defined also thanks next time ill ask how to fix the problem instead of thinking of something that will lead to a solution

Comment: its possible in C++ because you can use the void command to make C++ jump to whatever you put in front of void

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. The only way to make it error out is to input a non-number.

Comment: "its possible in C++ because you can use the void command to make C++ jump to whatever you put in front of void" - that is not how `void` works. It isn't even vaguely similar to how `void` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here can also be resolved by not making `x` a global variable and just a variable you can pass by value:

```
def timer(x):
    for n in range(x, 0, -1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(n)
    print("Times Up"+"\n")

def loop():
    x = int(input("Time for:"))
    timer(x)

#... loop() ... as many times as you want
```

No need for globalisation, much more pythonic - and in fact this is what'd you do in C as well because scopes of variables can become messy.

Also, you can iterate backwards through a range sequence, as shown above (This assumes `x` is a nonnegative integer).

Comment: Could you please explain why you need to put  in (x, 0, -1) instead of (0, x) and how it works.

Comment: `range(0,x)` will count from 0 to `x-1` with a step of 1 and `range(x,0,-1)` counts from `x` down to 1 with a step of -1. For a countdown the latter makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Short of placing `timer` above `loop`, as you correctly mention, you could save `timer` in its own module, then import it on top of the loop file.

Indeed, imported modules are first executed upon import.